# in-app versionCode does not reflect versionCode in Google Play Store

Tags: java, android, google-play, build.gradle, visual-studio-app-center

We are currently using AppCenter.ms to build & distribute our app, and autoincrement our `versionCode` value. The autoincrement seemingly works fine, and increments on Android and propagates to the google play store correctly as in the screenshot:

[image]

However, when using `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE` to display in our app (for customer support purposes), on navigating to the page in-app *on a build distributed by AppCenter or the Google Play Store (via AppCenter)*, it seems to always print out `1` which is the value stored in the repro before that app is compiled by AppCenter.

Obviously I would expect this to return the correct `versionCode` of `427` and it's going to cause our support staff a massive headache if we can't solve this before we get out of beta. The only thing I can think of is that Google Play and AppCenter are storing this value in such a way that the `build.gradle` of the compiled app isn't updated, and the code to get the `versionCode` is relying on that.

For reference here is a part of the `build.gradle` stored in the repository before compilation (I removed the `applicationId`):

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "***"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "3.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening or on how we can get the reported `versionCode` into our app correctly?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Have you tried using the `versionCode` field from `PackageInfo` instead?

Comment: Which gradle version are you using? You can initiate and seek help here https://github.com/Microsoft/appcenter/issues/45

Comment: @VVB gradle version is 5.1.1 but the linked issue is not the same as ours unfortunately.

Comment: @Michael Isn't PackageInfo deprecated in API 28 and up?

Comment: No. The `versionCode` field has been deprecated, bu that doesn't mean that you can't use it. And you can of course use `getLongVersionCode()` instead on API levels >= 28 if you want to.

Comment: @Michael This led me to the solution, thank you.